# Django multiple databases - correct router class

Tags: python, django, django-models

I would like to use two databases in my application:

- local database
- external database

in the first one I want to save all django tables , e.g auth_group

To do this I tried to use router class, but unsuccessfully - it doesn't work. Below you can find my code

Django 1.11

setings file:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['mainApp.models.DefaultDBRouter','subfolder.newApp.models.testDBRouter',]
```

models.py - main app - I want to use default DB for this model

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

class list_a( models.Model ):
    region = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Region")
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Country")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str( self.country )

class DefaultDBRouter(object):
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in the
    auth application.
    """

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Reads go to a default.
        """
        return "default"

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Writes always go to default.
        """
        return 'default'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Relations between objects are allowed if both objects are
        in the default.
        """
        db_list = ('default')
        if obj1._state.db in db_list and obj2._state.db in db_list:
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model=None, **hints):
        """
        All non-micro-management models end up in this pool.
        """
        return True
```

models.py - test app - I want to use second db for this model

```
class testTable( models.Model ):

    date = models.DateField(verbose_name="Date")
    number_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Number name")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str( self.number_name )


ELIGIBLE_APPS = [
   'subfolder.newApp',
]


class testDBRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        print model._meta.app_label
        if model._meta.app_label in ELIGIBLE_APPS:
            return 'secondDB'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in ELIGIBLE_APPS:
            return 'secondDB'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label in ELIGIBLE_APPS or \
                obj2._meta.app_label in ELIGIBLE_APPS:
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label in ELIGIBLE_APPS:
            return db == 'secondDB'
        return None
```

And if I execute the following command:

```
python2.7 manage.py migrate --database=secondDB
```

Then django creates all tables from both models files and standard django tables inside that database ( should create only one )

Answer (score 1):

I use two db and I do it in the following way 
and I do the normal migration .  python manage.py migrate

```
 DATABASES = {


'default': {
   'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
   'NAME': 'xxxx',
   'USER': 'root',
   'PASSWORD': '',
   'HOST': '',
   'PORT': '',

 },
 'base2': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
       'NAME': 'xxxxxx',
       'USER': '',
       'PASSWORD': '',
   },

}
```